# How do I select variable Regular expression using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some lines like below with numbers and strings. Some have only numbers while some have some strings as well before them:

```
'abc'            (17245...64590)
'cde'            (12244...67730)
'dsa'            complement (12345...67890)
```

I would like to extract both formats with and without numbers. So, the first two lines should contain only numbers while the third line should also contain string before the numbers.

I am using this command to achieve this.

```
result = re.findall("\bcomplement\b|\d+", line)
```

Any idea, how to do it.
Expected output would be like this:

```
17245, 64590
12244, 67730
complement, 12345, 67890
```

Comment: [`(\w+)?\s*\((\d+).*?(\d+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/EjgcyR/1)

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to match everything. Can you expand your example to include text that you're *not* trying to match? Also, is the text that comes before the numbers always "complement" or is that subject to change?

Comment: +CAustin I changed the input lines. This is how they look like. +anubhava: This select then only with 'complement' string and not the others. I want both of them to be extracted.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/pAQlsi

Comment: Can you add you expected matches for each case?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of digit chunks inside the parentheses is always 2 and they are separated with 1+ dots use

```
re.findall(r'\s{2,}(?:(\w+)\s*)?\((\d+)\.+(\d+)\)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FL9IG7/1). And a [sample Python demo](https://ideone.com/Krkja8):

```
import re
s= ''''abc'            (17245...64590)
'cde'            (12244...67730)
'dsa'            complement (12345...67890)'''
rx = r"\s{2,}(?:(\w+)\s*)?\((\d+)\.+(\d+)\)"
for x in re.findall(rx, s):
    print(", ".join([y for y in x if y]))
```

**Details**

- `\s{2,}` - 2 or more whitespaces
- `(?:(\w+)\s*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\.+` - 1 or more dots
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

If the number of digit chunks inside the parentheses can vary you may use

```
import re
s= ''''abc'            (17245...64590)
'cde'            (12244...67730)
'dsa'            complement (12345...67890)'''
for m in re.finditer(r'\s{2,}(?:(\w+)\s*)?\(([\d.]+)\)', s):
    res = []
    if m.group(1):
        res.append(m.group(1))
    res.extend(re.findall(r'\d+', m.group(2)))
    print(", ".join(res))
```

Both Python snippets output:

```
17245, 64590
12244, 67730
complement, 12345, 67890
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/u0uGSp). Note it can match any number of digit chunks inside parentheses and it assumes that are at least 2 whitespace chars in between Column 1 and Column 2.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzBOdk/1), too. The difference with the first one is that there is no third group, the second and third groups are replaced with one second group `([\d.]+)` that captures 1 or more dots or digits (the digits are later extracted with `re.findall(r'\d+', m.group(2))`).